# Import a row of data via csv to a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

this seems like it should be a simple question but I'm stuck.

I have a Book model and want to create a bunch of books via a csv that has a list of isbns. I created a rake task -

```
task :import_books => :environment do
    CSV.foreach('lib/books.csv', :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1:UTF-8') do |row|
      Book.create!({:isbn => row[0]})
    end
end
```

But am getting the following error -

ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"books", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

fwiw, from the console, I can create a record in all my other models with Model.create, but not Book.

I tried hardcoding in an id but it didn't work and doesn't seem ideal.

Thanks for any help!

edit -

Book migration (do you mean the schema?) -

```
create_table "books", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "author"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "link"
    t.integer  "score"
    t.boolean  "featured"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "likes"
    t.string   "cover_file_name"
    t.string   "cover_content_type"
    t.integer  "cover_file_size"
    t.datetime "cover_updated_at"
    t.string   "image_remote_url"
    t.string   "cover_url"
    t.string   "fake_cover"
    t.boolean  "permission"
    t.date     "release"
    t.string   "isbn"
  end
```

Book.new and Book.create from console -

2.1.2 :005 > Book.new
 => # 
2.1.2 :006 > Book.create
   (10.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (3.4ms)  INSERT INTO "books" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-01-26 17:50:11.119126"], ["updated_at", "2015-01-26 17:50:11.119126"]]
   (1.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"books", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:219:in `raise_generation_error'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:192:in`optimized_helper'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:178:in `call'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:270:in`block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
    from /Users/danifank/Documents/coverlist/app/models/book.rb:124:in `load_into_soulmate'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in`block in make_lambda'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `call'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in`block in halting_and_conditional'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `call'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in`block in halting_and_conditional'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in`run_callbacks'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:103:in`save'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in`save'
... 3 levels...
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in`transaction'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in`with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block in save'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:283:in`rollback_active_record_state!'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:267:in `save'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:34:in`create'
    from (irb):6
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in`start'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in`run_command!'
    from /Users/danifank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in`require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `'2.1.2 :007 >

Comment: can you post the book migration file, and also the output of `Book.new` from rails console.

Comment: just added -- Book.new works, but when I try b = Book.new followed by b.update_parameters, I get the same error

Comment: Do you have any pending migrations

Comment: no, i don't have any

Comment: so, I don't know if this counts as an answer, bc it doesn't really solve the problem - but if I do: `Book.create!({:isbn => row[0], :title => "dummy"})` then it will work.

Comment: It seems you have a callback in your Book model that calls load_into_soulmate (around book.rb:124) and that in turn is trying to use some routing helper. If you comment out your Book callbacks (ie after_save, after_create) you might find the save works without error.

Comment: Yes @Mike, now i see it :P